# Large aquarium floor load

Tags: floor, load-bearing

I'd like to put a 125 gallon aquarium in my entry area with a 55 or 75 sump tank underneath it. All told, I'm looking at likely 2250 to 2500 pounds over a base that's no more than 5 feet long by 20 inches deep. The floor joists are 2x10's, 16" OC. I'm looking at a spot up against a load-bearing foundation wall to put the aquarium. Is my floor strong enough to hold this weight, or should I reinforce it with additional support posts?

Comment: That's a pretty strong floor, so you're almost certainly OK, but if you want a proper load calculation you also need to know (a) how long the span is of your floor joists (length between the foundation wall and probably a beam) and (b) what other load is on that floor.

Comment: Also, what's the sump tank for? Temporary storage during water changes?

Comment: The sump tank is where the filtration happens - see http://aquaripure.com/setup/ for (an) example(s). There's no other load on that section of floor, though I'm not sure which way the joists run and they may go under a portion of the kitchen floor before hitting a beam or support post.